# Capture specified regex except for with specific end string

Tags: regex

Input String:

```
<ce:textbox-head><ce:title id="ti0015">Close-up: The front of the box</ce:title></ce:textbox-head><ce:title id="ti0010">Safety Lessons From Two Events Without Core Damage</ce:title>
```

Regex not working:

```
<ce:title(.*?)>(.*?)</ce:title>^((?!</ce:textbox-head>).)*$
```

Expected Output:

```
<ce:title id="ti0010">Safety Lessons From Two Events Without Core Damage</ce:title>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, could you please do cover your codes and samples in CODE TAGS for better understanding of it, thank you.

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/LqxIt2/1) what you want?

Comment: Yes. Thanks @tshiono

Comment: You don't need to replace `.` by `[^>]` or `[^<>]`  in my suggested pattern below.  Anyway, just any option you like.

Comment: The main difference is important if you allow nested tag(s) within `<ce:title` tag. Retaining using `.` allows you to further nest tags inside.   If no nested tag ever, it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?
`(?<=<\/ce:textbox-head>)(.*)`

**Explanation:**
Looks for everything behind `</ce:textbox-head>`

[image]

Comment: <ce:title(.?)>(.?)</ce:title> must be captured not any characters

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not going to match lines with `</ce:textbox-head>` altogether, you don't need to use Tempered Greedy Token.  Instead, you can use Negative Lookahead, like below:

```
(?!.*</ce:textbox-head>)(<ce:title(?:.*?)>.*?</ce:title>)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/R5rjzh/1/)

Explanation:

- `(?!.*</ce:textbox-head>)`   Negative lookahead to guard against matching any line with the unwanted pattern in the line
- `(<ce:title(?:.*?)>.*?</ce:title>)`  The expected matching group similar to what you code.  Put into a capturing group.

Note that with the Tempered Greedy Token construct like `(?!</ce:textbox-head>).)*` in your attempt, it does not stop you from matching any substring in the same line.  It just ensure the match, if any, does not include this pattern (but will still match the part not with this pattern).  As a result, the first line in your input will still be matched unexpectedly.